# levantar dos app que usan docker en servidor, a través del mismo puerto

Tags: docker, debian

Tengo dos aplicaciones, ambas están dockerizadas (front, back y bbdd expuestos a través de nginx) y ahora quiero subir ambas a servidor debian por el mismo puerto. Comotendría que realizar esto? configurar un Nginx "superior" que expongas las dos app?  en caso de ser así, como sería la configuración???

Comment: Por favor, delimita tu pregunta a un problema _específico_. En [es.so] no se dan tutoriales. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes **[configurar nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)** reverse proxy

Ejemplo

Grupo A ---> Frontend está mapeado al servidor debian con puerto 8081:80 (host:frontend docker)
Grupo B ---> Frontend esta mapeado al servidor debian con puerto 8082:80 (host:frontend docker)
Ahora con nginx reverse proxy

nginx bajo puerto 80 con Dominio_frontend_A reverse proxy al puerto 8081
nginx bajo puerto 80 con Dominio_frontend_B reverse proxy al puerto 8082

```
        server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  front_a.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8081;
      }
      server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  front_b.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8082;
      }
```